# Assign different css classes based on ID

Tags: php, wordpress, bbpress

1. This is what I have:

   [image: Actual output]
2. This is what I'm trying to achieve:

   [image: Desired output]

This is the code I'm trying to modify to achieve it:

```
<?php do_action( 'bbp_theme_before_topic_title' ); ?>


    <span class="bbp-topic-started-in"><?php
        printf( __('<a class="dog" href="%1$s">%2$s</a>', 'bbpress' ),
                bbp_get_forum_permalink( bbp_get_topic_forum_id() ),
                bbp_get_forum_title( bbp_get_topic_forum_id() ) );
    ?></span>
    <a class="bbp-topic-permalink" href="<?php bbp_topic_permalink(); ?>"><?php bbp_topic_title(); ?></a>
```

As you can see, it assigns the class "dog" to all forum links. I need it to assign separate classes to the different forums, based on the forum ID, so that I can style them differently.

What I'm thinking is maybe an `if` statement, but I'm not sure how to execute it properly. Anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
<?php do_action( 'bbp_theme_before_topic_title' ); ?>

<span class="bbp-topic-started-in">
<?php
    $forumId = bbp_get_topic_forum_id();

    // Replace these values with your forum IDs and css classes
    if ($forumId == 5) {
        $class = "dog";
    } elseif ($forumId == 6) {
        $class = "cat";
    } else {
        // Remember to specify a default css classname
        // in case we didn't match any of the 'if' cases above
        $class = "mouse";
    }

    // Use the $class variable that we set above to dynamically
    // replace the classname with the value we want
    printf( __('<a class="' . $class. '" href="%1$s">%2$s</a>', 'bbpress' ),
            bbp_get_forum_permalink($forumId),
            bbp_get_forum_title($forumId);
?>
</span>
```

Notice how I set `bbp_get_topic_forum_id()` to a variable and use it both in the `if` and in the `printf` further down. Doing this is good practice as it avoids needlessly calling that function multiple times.

Comment: Of course! Brilliant. Made some minor changes due to syntax errors. Thank you for your help!